# What can i do to make my car louder?

Tags: dodge

2014 dodge charger hemi r/t. I already got a rear muffler delete but it wasn't what i expected. I want it to be louder any suggestions?

Comment: Go open header? Weld in cut outs? Not sure how loud you want it to be. What is "loud" to you?

Comment: Please don't. The whole world doesn't want to hear your car.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while it may already have cast headers. I would suggest 2 things:

- tube headers (Headman is a good brand to trust)
- "glass packs" Fiberglass packed tube mufflers.

While you're there, you might want to consider using the largest diameter (exhaust) pipe you can get (3.5" to 4") from your Headers onward (which will mean matching the Glass Packs diameter to it).
You'll get a nice low rumble, with a soft popping sound. It's also a fairly inexpensive.

HTH